# Handling images with fixed em width and height

Tags: css

Here is how I handle images in my em based layout:

```
.model {
    width: 14.5em;
    float: left
    }

.model img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
```

The problem is some images differ in aspect ratio, dimensions and it brakes the layout.

So I am trying to give images a fixed size in em.

If i do this:

```
.model {
    width: 14.5em;
    float: left
    }

.model img {
    width: 14.5em;
    height: 14em;
    }
```

the height is set correctly but the width is smaller than 14.5em.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Tried it and it does not work, maybe there is something wrong with the css in other parts of my stylesheet...

Comment: could you provide us a fiddle how you tried?

Comment: I thought there could be an issue of having an em width img inside another div with em width (the image would somehow be relative to the outer div's width)

Comment: i cant investigate the site... for now try with overflow:hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are going unexpected width and height when we re-sizing  try the below methods:

```
.model {
    width: 14.5em;
    float: left
    }

.model img {
    max-width: 14.5em;
    height:auto;
    }
```

otherwise

```
.model {
    width: 14.5em;
    float: left
    }

.model img {
    width: auto;
    max-height:14.5em;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use max- and min- properties:

```
.model img {
width: 14.5em;
height: 14em;
max-height: 14.5em
min-height: 14.5em
}
```

Why not define width and height in the `img` tag (page rendering is faster)?

Comment: I have img urls, the images are not on my server, I have to resize them anyway so Im not sure it matters